# php group query results AFTER query

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My select query ($sql = "select day, hour, dollar from db";) output consists of 744 rows, one for every hour of a 31-day month. I echo them and it like this (commas for readability):

```
day 1, hour 1, dollars 300
day 1, hour 2, dollars 310
day 1, hour 3, dollars 299
/*etc., up to row 744, which looks like the following */
day 31, hour 24, dollars 200
```

So, 31 days with 24 hours each day, all in 744 rows.

In php, I want to group the rows by day, so that I get

```
da 1:
hour 1, dollars 300
hour 2, dollars 310
hour 3, dollars 299
..
hour 24, dollars 299
31:
24, 200
```

To set the `day` as a level above `hour` and `dollars`, I tried making an array, like so:

```
$arr[] = array( $day =>['hour' => $hour, 'dollars' => $dollars]);
```

`print_r($arr)` produces this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 1
            [dollars] => 300
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 2
            [dollars] => 310
        )

)
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 3
            [dollars] => 299
        )

)

// etc. up to:

Array
(
    [31] => Array
        (
            [hour] => 24
            [dolars] => 200
        )

)
```

... but what I need is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 
        [
            [hour] => 1
            [dollars] => 300
        ],
        [
            [hour] => 2
            [dollars] => 310
        ],
        [
            [hour] => 3
            [dollars] => 299
        ],
/*etc., up to */
        [
            [hour] => 24
            [dollars] => 200
        ]
)
```

Any suggestions about how I can I do this?

Comment: A +1 on the number of dimensions should do the trick. To avoid problems while managing indexes, first create the arrays for each day, then add these arrays to the global array.

Comment: `$arr[$day][] = ['hour' => $hour, 'dollars' => $dollars];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$arr[$day] []= array( 'hour' => $hour, 'dollars' => $dollars);
```